# How to do calculation using OpenGL ES 2.0/3.0?

Tags: opengl-es, gpgpu

i'm thinking a problem that is it possible to do some arrays calcution using OpenGL ES in mobile devices. For example, i used `glTexImage2D` to pass shader a float array (which contains some 0.0 and 1.0, such as {0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0...}), and i wish to figure out how many "1" are there in this array through Shader Language. Finally return the result to CPU. Is this possible? And how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could try renderscript (assuming you are on android).

If it's not feasible, you could try something like this:

What you want to do could be accomplished by writing these data into a texture, where every texel is 1 or 0 depending on the data. Then you should perform something like mip-mapping on this texture until you have only 1 pixel. Then that 1 pixel will have the average value of all pixels combined, so you can calculate back exactly how many of them were 1, by multipying it with the size of your initial float array. E.g. if that 1 pixel's value is 0.25, and you had 400 data, then 100 of them had the value of 1.

Note: If the data does not fit into a texture entirely, (for example you have an odd number of data), fill the unused texels with 0.

Note2: Float precision may ruin precision if you have too much data... Make sure you are using a single channel texture format with the highest precision. Single channel 32bit textures (which you should aim for) are only available in opengl es 3.0 afaik, but check the specs.

tldr; you should make a texture, generate mipmaps for it, read the last mip level, and multiply it's value by the number of data items

Comment: i'd like to know which is more efficient ? Renderscript or OpenGL ES? @agnu17

Comment: well i would say opengl es **could** be more efficient as it can use some hardware that renderscript can't. In this case im not sure if mipmap generation (glGenerateMipmap) is done by the cpu or the gpu. OpenGL allows both, it's up to the driver maker to implement the feature on either.
That said, if the driver is well implemented, the opengl version could be faster, because it can use some HW that renderscript can't. In Renderscript however you have to implement the mipmapping feature by hand, which is a bit harder, but it gives you a lot more control, and it's speed is more predictable

Comment: I'm a new hand in gpgpu, what i want to do now is to plant a section of code to GPU using OpenGL ES. I looked up some tutorials, and found out the FBO is needed. But I dont understand the using of FBO well. if i want to switch among these FBOs, when i unbind an FBO, will the data(texture in this fbo) be lost? And thank you for your patience again. : )

Comment: FBO is actually a texture. By calling 'glBindFramebuffer(int)' you can specify which texture to draw into. Even your screen can be thought of as an FBO, it even has the id of 0, that's why after you finish drawing into a framebuffer/texture you have to call 'glBindBuffer(0)', to set the screen as the drawing target.
Now, if you switch between Framebuffers's (you bind an other one) you dont erase it's data, so it won't be lost.
 If you want to erase data on your currently bound Framebuffer (be it the screen or an FBO) you have to call 'glClear(...)';

Comment: yes, i can understand what you said. But i have a question, if i bound FBO1, and drew something, then i bound another FBO2, would the drawing in FBO1 be deleted? Or it will save the drawing until i call glDeleteFrameBuffer?

Comment: yes, the drawing will be saved as long as you dont clear/delete it

Comment: i think i still have a long way in OpenGL. Your answers are really helpful. Thank you!